# Android - Create spinner programatically display issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, spinner

Basically, my program is prompting user to choose subjects from MainActivity's checkbox (maximum 5 from 10) and send its isChecked boolean value to NextActivity. With each true value receive, I need to create a spinner for user to choose grades between from A-F.

However, the issue is that the spinner in layout shows like that.

### [image: layout]

I created a class for creating spinner

```
public void createSpinner(String spinnerTitle, Spinner spinnerNumber){

    ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray.add(spinnerTitle);
    spinnerArray.add("A");
    spinnerArray.add("B");
    spinnerArray.add("C");
    spinnerArray.add("D");
    spinnerArray.add("F");

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
    spinnerNumber.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
}
```

Then, to get value from previous activity and check whether its true, for creating a spinner.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grade);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

    Spinner spinner1 = new Spinner(this);
    Spinner spinner2 = new Spinner(this);
    .....
    Spinner spinner10 = new Spinner(this);


    Boolean check01 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("C001");
    Boolean check02 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("C002");
    .....
    Boolean check10 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("C010");

    if (check01 == true) {
        createSpinner("Subject C0001",spinner1);
        layout.addView(spinner1);
    }
    if (check02 == true) {
        createSpinner("Subject C0002",spinner2);
        layout.addView(spinner2);
    }

    .....

    if (check10 == true) {
        createSpinner("Subject C0003",spinner3);
        layout.addView(spinner3);
    }
```

Please advice how to let the spinner to display vertically and placed in the centre.

An also, how can I detect which spinner is created, so that I can get the value user choose from the spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display it vertically you need to set `LinearLayout`'s orientation to `vertical`. You can do it like this in code.

```
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

To make `Spinner` appear in center set `layout`'s gravity to `CENTER_HORIZONTAL`.

```
LayoutParams layout_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Do I have a way to know that which spinner is created ?

Comment: @hatched I didn't get this part of the question. Can u explain it a bit more?

Comment: the program will only create a spinner when a `true` value is passed. Therefore I do not know whether which and how many spinner will be created. How would I detect that which spinner is created ?

Comment: @hatched You can create a `List` of `Spinner` and in `createSpinner` function just add that spinner the list.